# How can i pass the table values to modal in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, inheritance

When the edit option is clicked in the project, I want to transfer all the values in the relevant row into the modal, how can I do this?

here table body

```
<tbody class="list form-check-all">
                                                      
        {% for x in model %}
        
        <tr>
            
            <td class="id">{{x.name}}</td>
            <td class="company_name">{{x.phonenumber}}</td>
            <td class="leads_score">{{x.note}}</td>
            <td class="phone">{{x.status}}</td>
            <td class="location">{{x.callname}}</td>
            <td class="date">{{x.dataname}}</td>
            <td>
                <ul class="list-inline hstack gap-2 mb-0">
                    <li class="list-inline-item" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-trigger="hover" data-bs-placement="top" title="Edit">
                        <a class="edit-item-btn" href="#showModal" data-bs-toggle="modal"><i class="ri-phone-line fs-16"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

and here my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="showModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-light p-3">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" id="close-modal"></button>
            </div>
            <form action="">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" id="id-field" />
                    <div class="row g-3">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            
                            <div>
                                <label for="leadname-field" class="form-label">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" id="leadname-field" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--end col-->
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div>
                                <label for="company_name-field" class="form-label">Company Name</label>
                                <input type="email" id="company_name-field" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter company name" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--end col-->
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div>
                                <label for="leads_score-field" class="form-label">Leads Score</label>
                                <input type="text" id="leads_score-field" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter lead score" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--end col-->
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div>
                                <label for="phone-field" class="form-label">Phone</label>
                                <input type="text" id="phone-field" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter phone no" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--end col-->
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div>
                                <label for="location-field" class="form-label">Location</label>
                                <input type="text" id="location-field" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter location" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="hstack gap-2 justify-content-end">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="add-btn">Kaydet</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My codes are like this. When the edit option is clicked from here, I want to inherit the values of the relevant row in the table within the modal. How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe you need to use just Javascript to do that.

Answer (score 0):

so basically I would do that this way - when you load modal, the element that triggers it has `data-id` attribute and you send it over AJAX to the Django view. Then, before the modal's fully open, you change html code of the whole div, prepopulated with `single-instance` template that you send over using `JsonResponse`.

Something like that should work:

```js
const loadDetails = (e) => {
    let btn = $(e.currentTarget);
    const modalAjax = $("#modal-ajax");
    $.ajax({
        url: btn.attr("data-href"),
        type: 'GET',
        data: {id: <here_you_put_obj_id_using_data_attr>}
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            modalAjax.modal("show");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            modalAjax.find('.modal-content').html(data['html_form']);
        }
    });
};
```